# Maintaining selection state in ag-grid after reloading data

Tags: angular, ag-grid

For the record, this is in Angular 7

Surprisingly not a lot of info out on this. I have this "working" with a small snafu.  Generally I am hitting an endpoint to get snapshot data every N seconds.  I can't guarantee anything in the data: could be a totally new set every time.  Could be the same.  Could be the same data in different order.  The user could have some rows selected, and they need to be programatically re-selected after the data reloads.

Code in question below.  So, other than being pretty inefficient at n^2, it works, but there is a "flash" of the rows being temporarily being deselected.  Is there a way block rendering until the re-selection loop is complete?

I would be curious to hear other strategies to handle reselection.  Since in getMessages() I'm blowing out the rowData and putting it back in, the node IDs are completely different, so just searching by each ID and reselecting won't work.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
  reselect(selectedRows: Array<any>): void {
    for (const selectedRow of selectedRows) {
      this.gridApi.forEachNode( node => {
         if (node.data.id1 === selectedRow.id1 && node.data.id2 === selectedRow.id2) {
           node.setSelected(true);
         }
      });
    }
  }

  getMessages(): void {
    this.volumeService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        let selectedRows: Array<any> = new Array<any>();
        if (this.gridApi !== undefined) {
          selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
        }
        this.volumeDataWrapper = data;
        // Reselection needs to happen outside of this callback
        timer(0).subscribe( () => { this.reselect(selectedRows); });
      })
  }
```

Comment: Read these docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/. You're making it a bit hard on yourself with your current code.

Comment: Thank you -- I did not see that before.  It looks like Batch Update is supposed to be the best for my use case.  However, not sure that it will work as there is no unique ID per row.  I still need some mechanism to match the rows.

Comment: One thing you can do, rather than keeping track of the selected rows and the re-selecting them yourself, is tell the grid what is the ID of each row, and it should do it automatically: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-ids/#application-assigned-ids

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way block rendering until the re-selection loop is complete?

As far as showing rendering blocked until your re-selection loop gets completed, this answer can help you.
You can use `showLoadingOverlay` of `gridApi`.

```
getMessages(): void {

  this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay(); // <-

  this.volumeService.getData()
  .subscribe(data => {
    let selectedRows: Array<any> = new Array<any>();
    if (this.gridApi !== undefined) {
      selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
    }
    this.volumeDataWrapper = data;
    // Reselection needs to happen outside of this callback
    timer(0).subscribe( () => { 
     this.reselect(selectedRows);
     this.gridApi.hideOverlay(); // <-
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: I notice no difference w/ this approach. Tried doing the hiding in other places as well.

Comment: Updated the place where it shows loader. Give it a shot n let me know

Comment: I see the grid overlay... there is still a bit of a flash rendered.  I should probably attack the way I am handling reselecting.